# Creating java objects in loop without memory leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class memLeaks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException, IOException {
        while (true) {
            memLeak();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
}

public static void memLeak() throws AWTException, IOException {
    Robot robot1 = new Robot();
    Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    BufferedImage buff1 = robot1.createScreenCapture(rectangle1);
    File file1 = new File("randomPic.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(buff1, "jpg", file1);
    System.out.println(".");
    }
}
```

This is a random function that takes a 100x100 screen capture and saves it to a file over and over again. Now my problem is that when I open the task manager, memory used by this program is Forever increasing. But when I look the memory tab in JProfiler, it shows that Garbage Collector kicks in and trashes all the objects at some point. Is my task manager "lying" or how do you create a simple program that could run for hours without allocating all the memory in your computer. I also ran it from command line with same results. Without the "writing to a file", results are still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, Java is a garbage collected language, which means that memory isn't actually released until after one or more collection cycles are executed.  This leads the behavior you're seeing where memory usage steadily increases until some threshold is passed, and then drops drastically, only to start the process over.

One way around this is to tell (hint) to the runtime to perform a garbage collection now via the `System.gc();` call.  Note that this is a hint and doesn't actually force a garbage collection cycle.

```
    while (true) {
        memLeak();
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be working. I left the code running for an hour and task manager showed increase from 26M to 33M, whereas without the gc call it went up to 100MB quite quickly. But still, i dont understand whether the automatic gc works at all or is there some kind of upper bound? As well as the JProfiler that shows gc like everything was okay, but in reality the memory stays allocated.

Comment: Yes, the automatic gc works, but there there is no language requirement about when it occurs.  Indeed, it varies from VM to VM (hence System.gc() is a hint to gc, not a requirement to do it), the whole concept is that you shouldn't have to worry about it, it just automatically happens when the system deems it necessary and/or prudent.

Comment: Also note, that while this strongly encourages GC to run, it is still possible (seems likely actually given that usage is still gradually increasing) that you have an issue beyond just getting GC to run, mostly likely somewhere in `createScreenCapture`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to not closing your writers. try adding

```
file1.close();
buff1.close();
```

at the end of your memLeak method

Comment: "java.io.File doesn't represent an open file, it represents a path in the filesystem. Therefore having close method on it doesn't make sense.

Actually, this class was misnamed by the library authors, it should be called something like Path."